# What does adding or removing the question mark in sentences ending with ね change about the meaning, if anything?

Tags: grammar

What does adding or removing the question mark in sentences ending with ね change about the meaning, if anything?

> 暑いですね
>
> 暑いですね？

> 去年もそのシャツ着てたよね
>
> 去年もそのシャツ着てたよね？

Comment: In terms of written texts, ? would only disambiguate - without it, the sentences may or may not be questions. Are you asking the difference by falling/rising tone?

Comment: maybe? _________

Comment: Here are some related posts. I hope it helps: [27814](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27814/question-about-%e3%81%ad) [92846](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/92846/what-is-the-difference-between-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%ad-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%ad-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99)

Answer (score 1):

If you inflect your voice, you are generally seeking support/approval or outright asking a question in a casual way.

A response to seeking support would not be inflected.

> A: 暑いですね？
> B: ですね。

*note: the response would usually drop all the understood parts of the sentence.

*note: this is scratching the surface of the nuances of ね.

Answer (score 0):

The question mark signifies that you are asking the opinion of a person on something you accept as fact
While only ね makes the sentence a statement you are saying that you think is a fact
暑いですね means 'It sure is hot,'
暑いですね？ means 'It sure is hot, isn't it?'