# what is the difference between ○○ですね？、○○ですね、○○です、

Tags: words

what is the difference between

eg;

すてきですね？

すてきですね

すてきです

Answer (score 1):

**素敵ですね？** – Beautiful, isn't it?

**素敵ですね** – Oh, it's beautiful! (Something close to)

**素敵です** – It is beautiful. (Rather more formal and dry)

Note that 〜ね adds a gentle nuance to an expression or a sentence and somewhat appeals to the person listening.

Comment: I need little more explanation from 素敵ですね part

Comment: @yutrewq I can relate to you, but this answer is quite accurate. It's not so different from English especially in terms of the effect provided by the question mark - "Isn't it beautiful" is more of a statement while "Isn't it beautiful?" has a question-like nuance. Either way the ね adds a rhetorical nuance. Thus, regardless of the question mark, the speaker is anticipating an agreement such as はい. IMHO, 「素敵ですね？」 in its consolidated format looks strange taking into the trivial fact that question marks weren't integrated into Japanese syntax until the modern era.